# Can you have a background "app" process bluetooth input, and act as a switch-control input device?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, switchcontrol

We want to use eye blinks as input for switch control in iOS. We have a bluetooth device that broadcasts raw EEG over bluetooth, and it is easy to process those signals to determine when the wearer has blinked. But that processing does not happen on the device, it happens in code on the phone.

So: Is it possible to have something on the phone that is processing eeg, and when it sees a blink, will tell iOS that a switch-control press has happened?

Comment: No, you will need to process the data on some external device and have that device present a Bluetooth HID switch control profile to the iOS device.

Comment: @Paulw11 Consider submitting your response an answer. I'd upvote it.